# jQuery slide - element has wrong width/height

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI to animate an infobox. User clicks on an item, then an infobox pops up. It should slide out from the right and slide back when I want to hide it.

My code to show the infobox is as follows:

```
function ShowInfoBox() {
    var boxcontent = '<b>SOME HTML</b>';
    $("#infobox").html(boxcontent);

    $("#infoboxcontainer").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1300);
}
```

The `#infoboxcontainer` and the `#infobox` both have a CSS style of 100% width and height, so it fills up the parent item.

What happens is the following:

1. The item slides out, but it only has the smalles possible width/height (i.e. what the width/height would be if I didn't manipulate it). You see a tiny box travelling all they way across the page before it settles in the topleft corner.
2. When the sliding animation is complete, the element suddenly snaps to its intended width/height (i.e. 100%).

I can't seem to find a way to make the element slide after the width/height styles have properly been applied. I even tried setting timeouts etc but it seems it will always adjust the dimensions after revealing the item.

Anyone have an idea how to fix this?

*Side note: when hiding the item afterwards, it does not snap back to a smaller version. Hiding works like it should.*

Comment: When the element is sliding, it probably has an absolute position.  I am pretty sure you can't make an element 100% width when it has an absolute position set.

Comment: I thought so too. But my nfoboxcontainer now has the following css: position:absolute;
 left:10px;
 right:360px;
 bottom:92px;
 top:45px;
 -- instead of the 100% settings. Same issue as before.

Comment: Interesting.  Just for kicks, try setting a specified height/width in pixels and see if the behavior is the same.

Comment: It keeps its height when i set it to 500px. However, what bothers me the most: The slide animation starts sliding the element from the edge of the element itself (i silde from the right, so my sliding begins with the left side offset to the right, then it decreases the offset until the element is in place. however, my element starts sliding at the position it SHOULD be when 100%. But the element itself is displayed smaller that the sliding animation thinks it is...

Comment: Hmm... Not sure I could follow a 100% there.  Could you throw up an example on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Apparently, when you use `.show('slide', 'down',500)` the max width/heigt will be taken, then it will be animated. By using `.slideUp(500);` , the width/heigth is properly adjusted.

Solution: bug in jQuery UI :)